# Maze Solver DFS Algorithm

Tags: prolog, graph-algorithm, maze

I'm studying prolog in a course.
I have an exercise where I need to read a file, generate a maze from it, get a path from the source to destination and write it to a file.

I read the file and I assert `square(CoordX, CoordY)` for each cell I
have, and `connect(X, Y)` for each two cells that are connected.

`TargetX`, `TargetY`, `SourceX`, `SourceY` are all integer coordinates so I know the start point and destination point.

The rationale I worked by is, If current node is connected to target, finish and return. else, find a node that current node is connected to and call recursion with the new node

```
solveFirst(TargetX, TargetY, SourceX, SourceY, T):-
    connects(square(SourceX, SourceY), NewSquare),
    solve(TargetX, TargetY, SourceX, SourceY, NewSquare, T2),
    T = T2.

solve(TargetX, TargetY, SourceX, SourceY, NewSquare ,[Tail]):-
    getFirst(Tail, HeadOfTail),
    (
    connects(NewSquare, square(TargetX, TargetY)), 
    addFirst(NewSquare, Tail, T2),
    Tail = T2 ;
    connects(NewSquare, E),
    solve(TargetX, TargetY, SourceX, SourceY, E, Tail)
    ).
```

Answer (score 2):

Your rationale seems valid. The only thing left for you to do is to implement it correctly.

First, a general comment about your code:

When you see a goal like:

```
T = T2
```

ask yourself: *Why did you introduce `T2` **at all**?* You can simply use `T` *instead*, since these are *the same term* if this goal succeeds.

This pattern arises **twice** in your program.

Another issue: **Never** put `;` at the *end* of a line It looks too similar to `,`.

So, after these changes, your `solve/6` looks like this:

```
solve(TargetX, TargetY, SourceX, SourceY, NewSquare, [Tail]):-
    getFirst(Tail, HeadOfTail),
    (   connects(NewSquare, square(TargetX, TargetY)),
        addFirst(NewSquare, Tail, Tail)
    ;   connects(NewSquare, E),
        solve(TargetX, TargetY, SourceX, SourceY, E, Tail)
    ).
```

Now ask yourself: *Does this even make sense?* In particular, can `addFirst(NewSquare, Tail, Tail)` *ever* succeed? It's kind of hard to tell for us, since you have *omitted* its definition.

Also, when you compile this, you get a **warning**:

```
Singleton variables: [HeadOfTail]
```

So why did you even introduce this variable?

Conceptually, the following pattern may help you:

```
path(Current, Target, Path) :-
    (   connects(Current, Target),
        Path = [Current]
    ;   connects(Current, Next),
        Path = [Current|Ps],
        path(Next, Target, Ps)
    ).
```

Answer (score 2):

I've modified your rules in this way

```
solve(TargetX, TargetY, _, _, NewSquare, [NewSquare]) :-
  connects(NewSquare, square(TargetX, TargetY)).

solve(TargetX, TargetY, SourceX, SourceY, NewSquare, [E | Tail]) :-
  connects(NewSquare, E),
  solve(TargetX, TargetY, SourceX, SourceY, E, Tail).

solveFirst(TargetX, TargetY, SourceX, SourceY, [NewSquare | T]):-
  connects(square(SourceX, SourceY), NewSquare),
  solve(TargetX, TargetY, SourceX, SourceY, NewSquare, T).
```

and, with the following facts

```
square(1, 1).  square(1, 2).  square(1, 3).
square(2, 1).  square(2, 2).  square(2, 3).
square(3, 1).  square(3, 2).  square(3, 3).

connects(square(1, 1), square(1, 2)).
connects(square(1, 1), square(2, 1)).
connects(square(1, 2), square(1, 3)).
connects(square(1, 2), square(2, 2)).
connects(square(2, 1), square(2, 2)).
connects(square(2, 2), square(3, 2)).
connects(square(3, 2), square(3, 3)).
```

calling `solveFirst(3, 3, 1, 1, L)`, I get (in `L`) the following paths

```
[square(1,2),square(2,2),square(3,2),square(3,2)]
[square(2,1),square(2,2),square(3,2),square(3,2)]
```

But this work because there aren't loops. If you add the following connection

```
connects(square(2, 2), square(1, 2)).
```

so you can loop ((1,2) -> (2,2) -> (1,2) -> (2,2) ...) and from `solveFirst(3, 3, 1, 1, L)` I get a stack overflow.

To avoid this problem, you can remember the visited squares and avoid to use them again.

I've written the following example but consider that

(1) I've switched start and target (start first, target second)

(2) I've added start and target in the resulting path

(3) I'm using gprolog so I don't have `not/1`; I've used `\+ member....` instead

```
getPath(Tx, Ty, Tx, Ty, _, [square(Tx, Ty)]).

getPath(Sx, Sy, Tx, Ty, Visited, [square(Sx, Sy) | Path]) :-
  connects(square(Sx, Sy), square(Nx, Ny)),
  \+ member(square(Nx, Ny), Visited), % or not(member(square(Nx, Ny), Visited)
  getPath(Nx, Ny, Tx, Ty, [square(Nx, Ny) | Visited], Path).

getPath(Sx, Sy, Tx, Ty, Path) :-
  getPath(Sx, Sy, Tx, Ty, [square(Sx, Sy)], Path).
```

Using the following facts

```
square(1, 1).  square(1, 2).  square(1, 3).
square(2, 1).  square(2, 2).  square(2, 3).
square(3, 1).  square(3, 2).  square(3, 3).

connects(square(1, 1), square(1, 2)).
connects(square(1, 1), square(2, 1)).
connects(square(1, 2), square(1, 3)).
connects(square(1, 2), square(2, 2)).
connects(square(2, 2), square(1, 2)).
connects(square(2, 1), square(2, 2)).
connects(square(2, 2), square(3, 2)).
connects(square(3, 2), square(3, 3)).
```

from `getPath(1, 1, 3, 3, L)` I get the following paths

```
[square(1,1),square(1,2),square(2,2),square(3,2),square(3,3)]
[square(1,1),square(2,1),square(2,2),square(3,2),square(3,3)]
```

**--- EDIT ---**

As suggested by Mat in a comment (thanks!), instead of `\+ member(square(Nx, Ny), Visited)` (or `not(member(square(Nx, Ny), Visited)`) you could write (if your prolog environment support `maplist/2`)

```
maplist(dif(square(Nx,Ny)), Visited)
```

to impose that `square(Nx, Ny)` isn't in the `Visited` list.

This solution is more general because (if I understand correctly) the unification works in both directions.

Comment: Good solution, +1! Only one small suggestion: Consider using `dif/2` to express that two terms are different. This makes your predicate more general.

Comment: @mat - thanks; I'm even surprised that someone understand what I write; but ... where I should use `dif/2`?

Comment: `maplist(dif(square(Nx,Ny)), Visited)` states: `square(Nx,Ny)` is *different* from each of the elements in `Visited`. Critically, this works correctly in *all* directions, also if `Visited` is not instantiated. Therefore, `dif/2` makes your code more versatile and general.

Comment: @mat - really interesting; unfortunately my gprolog (1.3.0, in a debian environment) is too old to support `maplist/2`; but I'll add you suggestion in the answer.